# Binded ImageView disappears when scrolling RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've created a Leaderboard activity in my app where I show the top 25 users in a `RecyclerView`.

It all works well when it is loaded and it appears as:

[image]

However, for some reason, when I scroll the `RecyclerView` it removes the medals and it shows:

[image]

My adapter is:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    otherUserID = usersID.get( position );
    otherUserName = usersName.get( position );
    if (tabCase == 0) {
        String result = String.format( "%.2f", usersResult.get( position ) );
        otherUserResult = result;
    } else {
        otherUserResult = String.format( "%.0f", usersResult.get( position ) );
    }
    holder.tv_PersonName.setText( otherUserName );
    holder.tv_Result.setText( otherUserResult );
    holder.tv_Ranking.setText( Integer.toString( position + 1 ) );


    if (position == 0) {
        holder.iv_Medal.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_gold_medal );
    } else if (position == 1) {
        holder.iv_Medal.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_silver_medal );
    } else if (position == 2) {
        holder.iv_Medal.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_bronze_medal );
    } else {
        holder.iv_Medal.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    }
    storageRef.child( "/Images/" + otherUserID + ".jpg" ).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener( uri -> Glide.with( mView.getContext() ).load( uri.toString() ).into( holder.iv_PersonPic ) ).addOnFailureListener( e -> {
        Glide.clear( holder.iv_PersonPic );
        holder.iv_PersonPic.setImageDrawable( null );
    } );

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener( v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent( mView.getContext(), UsersPreviewActivity.class );
        intent.putExtra( AppConstants.PREVIEW_KEY, otherUserID );
        mView.getContext().startActivity( intent );
    } );

}
```

Any way to make those medals stick to the first 3?

Thank you

Comment: And where you are showing it again, when it is recycled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the following in other if conditions and set the view to VISIBLE

```
holder.iv_Medal.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE);
```

like so:

```
if (position == 0) {
    holder.iv_Medal.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_gold_medal );
    holder.iv_Medal.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE);
} else if (position == 1) {
    holder.iv_Medal.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_silver_medal );
    holder.iv_Medal.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE);
} else if (position == 2) {
    holder.iv_Medal.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_bronze_medal );
    holder.iv_Medal.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    holder.iv_Medal.setVisibility( View.GONE );
}
```